# How to show that $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt {-1}) \cong \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 2) \cong \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 5)$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

How to show that $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt {-1}) \cong \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 2) \cong \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 5)$ ?

There is a lemma which says that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt a) \cong \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt b)$ iff $a/b$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

If I use this lemma, then $2/5$ must be square in $Q_3$ if $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 2) \cong \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 5)$.

**But how to show $2/5$ is square in** $\mathbb{Q}_3$ ?

Any simple way to understand rather than using Hensel lemma.

Comment: Hensel${}{}{}$?

Comment: If an integer $n$ is congruent to $1\pmod3$ then Hensel tells us $\sqrt{n}\in\Bbb{Q}_3$. Therefore $\sqrt{10}\in\Bbb{Q}_3$. $\sqrt{10}=\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Note that $2/5=1-3/5$. Recall that in $\mathbb{R}$, there is a “formal” power series expansion $\sqrt{1-x}=\sum_n{\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^nn!(n-1)!}(-x)^n}=\sum_n{(-1)^n\binom{2n-1}{n}\frac{x^n}{2^n(2n-1)}}$. For $x=3/5$, the series is convergent in the $3$-adic norm: the formal identity becomes a $p$-adic one.

Comment: Also Hensel lemma is very elementary, you can't be affraid by it : if $f$ is separable $\bmod p$ from a root $\bmod p$ we can construct a $p$-adic root by solving  the $p^k$-coefficients one by one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, So $\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 5 \in \mathbb{Q}_3$ but how this is linked with showing $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 2) = \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt 5)$ ?

Comment: Much the same reason as why $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)=\Bbb{Q}(3/\sqrt2)$. Instead of $\Bbb{Q}$ we have $\Bbb{Q}_3$, and instead of $3\in\Bbb{Q}$ we have $\sqrt{10}\in\Bbb{Q}_3$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen very nice and tricky sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Perhaps fruitful is to reframe the question as: How can I show that something is *not* a square in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.  I came to this by picking some random multiples of $1/5$ and trying to decide whether they were squares in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.)

(I've never seen an argument of this form before, so I may have inadvertently overlooked one or more subtleties.  I really should read more on $p$-adics.)

Suppose $x^2 =_{\mathbb{Q}_3} \dfrac{a}{5}$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., $a \in \mathbb{Q}_3$ having a finite $3$-adic expansion) and $x \in \mathbb{Q}_3$.  From the form of [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel's_lemma_for_p-adic_numbers), we wish to study the polynomial $f(x) = 5x^2 - a$.  Hensel's lemma allows us to extend a prefix of a solution, $y \cong x \pmod{3^k}$, to $f(x) = 0$ as long as $f'(y) \neq 0$.  Since 
$$   f'(y) = 10 y = 3^2 y + y =_{\mathbb{Q}_3} 0  $$ requires $y \cong 0 \pmod{9}$ (because the first two $3$-adic digits of $y$ are unaffected by adding $3^2 y$), we may instead study 
$$  5 x^2 - a \cong 0 \pmod{9}  $$
where a value of $a$ forcing $x \cong 0 \pmod{9}$ is a necessary condition that $a/5$ is *not* a square in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.  Applying that constraint on $x$, we find $a \cong 0 \pmod{9}$ may create an obstruction to Hensel's lemma.<sup>1</sup>  Consequently, any other choice of $a$ produces a square in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

Since $-1 \cong 8 \not \cong 0 \pmod{9}$ and $2 \not \cong 0 \pmod{9}$, $-1/5$ and $2/5$ are squares in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.  With the lemma you state and a very short argument about transitivity, you get the three way field isomorphism.

<sup>1</sup><sub>: The condition $a \cong 0 \pmod{9}$ is necessary, but is not sufficient to obstruct a lift, as described at the cited Wikipedia article.  Just because a $p$-adic prefix of a number is zero does not mean that the number is zero.  As long as the number is not zero, a slightly more complicated procedure extends the prefix.  The argument above allows the existence of $a \cong 0 \pmod{9}$ which produce squares in $\mathbb{Q}_3$, but the particular choices of $a$ you are considering do not require examining this further.</sub>